# Deny every action on an organisation unit for a group in phpLDAPadmin (LDAP)

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to deny every access for a group (group `trainees` like in my picture) to the organisation unit `Ulist` in my phpLDAPadmin. How can I do it ?

I don't know how to configure a simple access control with LDAP.

[image: My phpLDAPadmin]

Thanks !

Comment: Access control is not supposed to be done on a frontend. What LDAP server are you using?

Comment: I use openLDAP.